# Two table column merge in one column in T3 Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Create two table Table1 and Table2.

```
Table1
4
2
1
```

```
T2
P
Q
R
```

Write a SQL query to display a drive of table T3 from T1 and T2.

```
Table3
4PPPP
2QQ
1R
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t1.num, repeat(t2.str,t1.num)
 from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

> ```
> num | repeat(t2.str,t1.num)
> --: | :--------------------
>   4 | PPPP                 
>   2 | QQ                   
>   1 | R
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0daf4c0c4dff46c280212818a99614a0)*